# Just installed 3scale API Management in Openshift cluster and i am unable to see the self-managed gateway

Tags: api, openshift, redhat, api-gateway, 3scale

Used the template provided here :- https://github.com/3scale/3scale-amp-openshift-templates/blob/master/amp/amp.yml

Under integration tab , i am unable to see the option for APICast self managed gateway option.

[image: MISSING SELF MANAGED APICAST]

Comment: You could do it out of the box in a 2.6 or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

From the graphics I would assume the version you installed is 2.3 or lower.

My suggestion is to try with the latest stable template (2.8)